# Showing Multiple Control Types in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

All, I have created a `TabControl` to hold `Tabitem`s that contain a single control type. The markup for `MainWindow.xaml` *was* as shown below

```
...
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" 
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            TabStripPlacement="Top" 
            Margin="5,0,5,0">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Views:ResourceControl DataContext="{Binding}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
...
```

This worked great for my `Views:ResourceControl`s but I now want to extend the type of controls displayed in the `TabControl`. To do this I create controls that are both linked to view models that inherit from a base 'WorkspaceViewModel' and I have created the following resource file

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.ViewModels"
                    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Views">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ResourceDataViewModel}">
        <Views:ResourceControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:StartPageViewModel}">
        <Views:StartPageControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" 
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    TabStripPlacement="Top" 
                    Margin="5,0,5,0">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and now in the `MainWindow.xaml` I have

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style x:Key="DescriptionHeaderStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}">
</ContentControl>
```

The bindings seem to register for the different views I want to display as the tabs display with the relevant headers. However, the actual controls do not display until I load another form. It seems that the `SelectedIndex` is not binding and the views not being updated when the tab item is switched/loaded.

**How can I change the `WorkspaceTemplate` to fix this problem?**

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit. Requested information regarding the MainViewModel.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel 
{
    private readonly IDialogService dialogService;
    private WorkspaceViewModel selectedWorkspace;
    private ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> workspaces;
    private Dictionary<string, string> resourceDictionary;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        base.DisplayName = "SomeStringName";
        resourceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dialogService = ServiceLocator.Resolve<IDialogService>();
        Contract.Requires(dialogService != null);
    }

    ...

    private void OnWorkspacesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (WorkspaceViewModel workspace in e.NewItems)
                workspace.RequestClose += this.OnWorkspaceRequestClose;

        if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (WorkspaceViewModel workspace in e.OldItems)
                workspace.RequestClose -= this.OnWorkspaceRequestClose;
    }

    private void OnWorkspaceRequestClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WorkspaceViewModel workspace = sender as WorkspaceViewModel;
        workspace.Dispose();
        int currentIndex = Workspaces.IndexOf(workspace);
        this.Workspaces.Remove(workspace);
        if (this.Workspaces.Count > 0)
            this.SetActiveWorkspace(Workspaces[currentIndex - 1]);
    }

    private void SetActiveWorkspace(WorkspaceViewModel workspace)
    {
        Debug.Assert(this.Workspaces.Contains(workspace));
        ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Workspaces);
        if (collectionView != null)
            collectionView.MoveCurrentTo(workspace);
    }

    public WorkspaceViewModel SelectedWorkspace
    {
        get { return selectedWorkspace; }
        set { selectedWorkspace = value; }
    }   

    private int selectedIndex = 0;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedIndex == value)
                return;
            selectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the collection of available workspaces to display.
    /// A 'workspace' is a ViewModel that can request to be closed.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (workspaces == null)
            {
                workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
                workspaces.CollectionChanged += this.OnWorkspacesChanged;
            }
            return workspaces;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can we see your VM code containing `SelectedIndex` property, and what do you exactly mean when saying loading the form?

Comment: @AsitK the question has been updated. Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced something similar by using your code. Not sure if it is the same one. When my application loaded it showed the 1st tab (0th) with its proper content. When select the 2nd content region got blank and nothing happened.

I moved the `Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"` to the `TabControl` i.e.

`Content="{Binding}"` and

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}"/>
```

and it started to show the content for the tabs. I used more stripped down version of your VM. just the collection of `WorkSpaces`.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you. Although I am not quite sure why this is working over the approach above. The cascading of the binding should go up the element tree and this seems to me to be going _down_!?

Comment: For your original bindings, I checked the Binding Errors in the Output window and it showed that `SelectedIndex` property was not found on the `WorkspaceVM`, i.e. it was looking for it on the wrong VM. Moreover if nothing was shown selected and I minimized the window, taking keyboard focus to some different window and moved back to it, then it showed the selected tab content.. strange..!!!!  The new binding made sure that the `DataContext` for your `TabControl` was `MainWindowVM` and `SelectedIndex` was fetched from   it. Looks like keeping IEnumberable as DataContext is not a good idea..